How to detect divergence at a transaction/message level in Aeron Cluster?
How can we detect divergence in an Aeron cluster and take the diverging node out of the cluster?
For example if we have a 3 node aeron cluster, if one of the nodes in the cluster diverges from the other two nodes, how can we monitor and detect divergence as soon as it happens and prevent the diverging node from being elected the leader.

We could periodically generates snapshot of state on all 3 nodes in the cluster, hash the snapshots and verify they are the same.

But snapshots are only generated periodically, and divergence maybe detected too late. And a diverging node could be elected as leader.

Every time a message/transaction is processed, the resultant state/outcome on each cluster node should be compared, and if divergence is noticed, a message logged/alert generated identifying the message/transaction whose processing caused the divergence and the diverging node should be taken out of the cluster.

A problem ( i think) that should be taken into account, is the 3 cluster members may not all process a transaction/message at the exact same time. One or more members may be behind the others in processing messages from the log and therefore the comparison may have to wait until all members have had an opportunity to process the message.
Is this possible in Aeron cluster?
I have tried using snapshotting and writing transaction results to an archive and tracking archive positions to detect divergence.
But would like to see if there are better ways of detecting divergence

we could take all care to ensure that application log is deterministic as mentioned in
https://aeron.io/docs/cluster-quickstart/replicated-state-machines/#determinism
But would still like to monitor the cluster for divergence and take action immediately

You could create an additional recorded IPC publication from within the clustered service that records all messages that are outbound (let's call this the egress-log). A separate application/process can then read the recorded egress log of each cluster node and compare the messages to detect divergence. To help manage the comparison of messages by this "divergence detecter" process I would have the cluster stamp each message with a monotonically increasing sequence number so you can ensure you properly comparing the same message (as well as detect gaps/dupes).

Thanks! That seems like a valid approach to divergence detection

Each cluster node after processing a message/transaction from the log, could publish the result of processing back as a message into the cluster log.
A separate clustered service running in the same cluster could look for all the results, check if any of the result is different from the others and determine divergence. We would know exactly which transaction caused divergence.
Once divergence is detected, would have to check if Aeron permits reconfiguring the cluster dynamically by removing the divergent node from the cluster.
One problem though with this approach, is for every transaction processed in the cluster, 3 additional messages for transaction results ( for each of the 3 cluster nodes) would be added back into the cluster. This may affect the throughput of the cluster
